# How to process multiple files through a program in bash using a predefined number of processes?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I'm running a computationally heavy program on a list of files in bash. If I do them one at a time, I do not utilize my computer power, yet if I append the `&` symbol to the command to run them in background processes, I'm running too many. What I'm looking for is a way to specify that I want `n` processes to work through a particular list of items files. When one finishes, it moves on to another.

As a minimal example, here is some setup code to replicate my situation:

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test

$for i in {1..1000}
>do
>   echo "$i" >> $i.txt
> done
```

How would I use (say) 2 processes only to process this list of files so that the output in each file does some arbitrary operation to the number `$i` (maybe add two or something) and then prints, `done by process 1 or 2`, depending on whether process 1 or 2 did the operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parallelize for-loop in bash limiting number of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774355/how-to-parallelize-for-loop-in-bash-limiting-number-of-processes)

Comment: Here's how you can do it in pure in-shell, possibly without nonstandard external utils: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475/23692.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not very sensible so it is hard to advise you better, but you can use **GNU Parallel** for this.

Say you want to run `HeavyProcessing` on all files starting with `SeriousData` using two CPU cores in parallel:

```
parallel -j 2 HeavyProcessing ::: SeriousData*
```

Slightly different example, say the filenames you want to process are in a file called `FileList.txt` and you want to run one process per core that your CPU has and also get a progress bar:

```
parallel -a FileList.txt --bar HeavyProcessing
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be `xargs -P` but it requires some extra noise to make it work. Here is a solution that maps to your example:

```
printf '%s\0' {1..1000} | xargs -0 -rn1 -P2 bash -c 'echo "$1" >> "$1".txt' --
```

explanation:

- `-0`: separate input parameters at `\0` byte (because that's what `printf '%s\0' …` sends)
- `-r`: don't run anything, if there is no input
- `-n1`: use only one input parameter per process
- `-P2`: use at most 2 parallel processes
- `bash -c '…' --`: the program to run; running a shell from xargs requires `--` to properly bind the positional parameters
- `'echo "$1" >> "$1".txt'`: the actual piece of shell code

The last pieces get a lot easier, if the bulk code you want to run does not require special shell features like redirection. You could run your program explicitly from xargs without a `bash -c` indirection.