# How to capture the output of openssl command that is running in the background instantly

Tags: shell, openssl

I've about 300+ servers to check if a particular port is open.

OpenSSL is taking over 5 minutes to respond with the whole output. But I don't need the whole output. I just want to see the `CONNECTED` message which pops up instantly if valid.

So, I'm terminating OpenSSL after few seconds using the below code.

Sample output:
`[345534@localhost tmp]$ echo "x" | openssl s_client -connect 192.168.18.10:500
CONNECTED(00000003)
^C`

For that, I'm using:

`echo "x" | openssl s_client -connect 192.168.18.10:500 &
sleep 4
echo "Teriminating openssl for cleanup."
pkill -f openssl
echo "done"`

Question:
Is there a way to capture the OpenSSL command (running in the background) output without waiting for 5 minutes to determine if the port connection is established or not?

I've tried the below procedure, no go:

`echo "x" | openssl s_client -connect 192.168.18.10:500 > /tmp/_out &`

`sleep 4`

`a=$(</tmp/_out)`

`echo $a`

`pkill -f openssl`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `timeout` instead of having to background your `openssl` command?

```
# save the exit code on the same line to prevent future bugs if
# someone inserts any code between the openssl call and the if block
timeout 4 openssl s_client -connect 192.168.18.10:500 >/tmp/_out 2>/tmp/_error; ec=$?
if ((ec == 124)); then
  # openssl timed out
elif ((ec != 0)); then
  # openssl failed
  cat /tmp/_error
else
  # openssl succeeded
  cat /tmp/_out
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but ec value is always getting to 124-timed out. any clue why would that happen?

Comment: Looks like openssl is timing out each time.  Increase your timeout value.  When it times out, it may not produce any output.  In any case, I have updated the answer to send stderr to a different file.

Comment: I've just tried with timeout value 100 and 200.  ec value doesn't change from 124.
Couldn't get the output saved in /tmp/_out or /tmp/_error.

Comment: What happens if you call `openssl` without the timeout?  Does it finish within a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: That is the original problem. `OpenSSL` is taking over 4 to 5 minutes to respond with the whole output. But I don't need the whole output. I just want to see the `CONNECTED` message which pops up instantly if valid.

Comment: That is a very different requirement.  Please update your question accordingly and I would be glad to update the answer to address your problem.

Comment: Sure. Updated the question. I just want to reduce the time while I run OpenSSL commands. Any suggestions on that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the PID of your most recently executed background (asynchronous) command in $!. You might operate with that.

```
cat server_list | while read s; do
  echo "x" | openssl s_client -connect 192.168.18.10:500 > /tmp/_out_$s &
  export opensslPid=$!
  # open a new shell, and send in background immediately
  (sleep $timeOut; echo "Killed with timeout" >> /tmp/_out_$s; kill $opensslPid)&
done
```

What you have left is monitor the files in /tmp/*out**.

If you don't want all 300 process to run in parallel, you might try something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/is-there-a-limit-to-processes-i-can-run-in-the-background or [Bash: limit the number of concurrent jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537956/bash-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-jobs)

Comment: Sorry if I missed giving the complete picture. I'm using puppet/rundeck to push the script to the servers and it can wait can fetch the output. `echo "x"` terminates the OpenSSL process once done. I was really checking for a way to do it faster without waiting for the whole output. But it looks like it isn't easy.