# How to pause loop after x loops for x seconds

Tags: bash

How can I pause my loop after x loops for x seconds?

My loop reads a list of IP addresses line by line. After 50 loops it should pause x seconds till the loop continues.

Comment: Nope...it is not a duplicate of this questions.

Comment: `sleep $x` should do it.

Comment: After 50 loops...

Comment: So you want us to write the script for you, instead of you searching Google how to use a loop with a counter and a conditional.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537956/bash-limit-the-number-of-concurrent-jobs

Answer (score 0):

```
while read IP
do
<command>

# Sleep
((c++)) && ((c==50)) && sleep 60

done < input_file.txt
```

Comment: You can put the `&&` inside a single `((...))` statement. `(( c++ && c == 50))`. However, do you want to pause *again* after another 50 lines? You need to reset the value of `c` to 0. An explicit `if` statement is probably cleaner: `if (( c == 50)); then c=0; sleep 60; else ((c++)); fi`.

Comment: Yes, I want to pause again after another 50 lines. Thank you!