# Running perl code using `atom` throws me Undefined subroutine &main::send_request

Tags: perl

I'm writing my first `perl` script for the requirement

- generate HTTP request against a particular web uri in succession using different URL scheme patterns

> ```
> use HTTP::Request::Generator 'generate_requests';
> use URI;
> use HTTP::Request::Common;
> use strict; # safety net
> use warnings; # safety ne
> use Test::LWP::UserAgent 'send_request';
> use LWP::UserAgent 'send_request';
> use Test::More;
> use URI;
> use HTTP::Request::Common;
> use LWP::UserAgent;
>
>
>
> my $g = generate_requests(
>     method => 'POST',
>     host   => ['example.com','www.example.com'],
>     pattern => 'https://example.com/{bar,foo,gallery}/[00..99].html',
>
>
>     wrap => sub {
>         my( $req ) = @_;
>         # Fix up some values
>         $req->{headers}->{'Content-Length'} = 666;
>     },
> );
> while( my $r = $g->()) {
>     send_request( $r );
> };
> ```

I'm using `atom` editor and `activeperl` on windows 10, I get following error from running above code.

`Undefined subroutine &main::send_request called at C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\0ac821e0-0886-11eb-9588-291dbc37d883 line 57.`

I have already installed all necessary modules and lib but i think its unable to refer the method `send_request`. Pls assist.

**NOTE**
I have replaced real values in variable for privacy reasons.

**UPDATE**

I plan to use following module
`pattern => 'https://example.{com,org,net}/page_[00..99].html',` from
https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Generator.

Comment: Looks like you don't actually solve the problem you've been asked to solve. All of your generated requests will use the same URL scheme - https.

Comment: @DaveCross thats my inital code in real it be https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Generator done through `pattern => 'https://example.{com,org,net}/page_[00..99].html'`

Comment: I guess my point is that HTTP::Request::Generator might be overkill for a task where you just want to change HTTP to HTTPS :-)

Comment: @DaveCross infact i moved to this custom solution because this failed for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195729/stress-testing-uri-using-xargs-curls-bash-script-failing-with-status-empty. I want to avoid timeout condition for 504 http requests..thats my main goal.

Comment: I very much doubt that changing your client software will fix 504 problems. You will still be sending the same requests (or something vert similar).

Comment: @DaveCross so its something that cannot be controlled at client side?

Comment: Well, It's not impossible, but it seems unlikely. It means that the server is taking too long to respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LWP::UserAgent is an object-oriented module. It doesn't export functions. You want to call `send_request` like this:

```perl
my $ua = 'LWP::UserAgent'->new;

while ( my $r = $g->() ) {
    $ua->send_request( $r );
}
```

That said, `send_request` is an undocumented internal method. I think it is probably more intended for people who are subclassing LWP::UserAgent. You probably want the `request` method instead.

```perl
my $ua = 'LWP::UserAgent'->new;

while ( my $r = $g->() ) {
    my $response = $ua->request( $r );
}
```

Full code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Request::Generator 'generate_requests';
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = 'LWP::UserAgent'->new;

my $gen = generate_requests(
    method  => 'POST',
    host    => [ 'example.com', 'www.example.com' ],
    pattern => 'https://example.com/{bar,foo,gallery}/[00..99].html',
    wrap    => sub {
        my ( $req ) = @_;
        # Fix up some values
        $req->{'headers'}{'Content-Length'} = 666;
    },
);

while ( my $req = $gen->() ) {
    my $response = $ua->request( $req );
    
    # Do something with $response here?
}
```

Comment: I ran your code, it says `You need a request object, not '666' at E:\501dos.pl line 20.` Do i need to put quotes around `666` this is just an example infact i want to pass many headers so `headers => [ { "Content-Type" => 'text/plain; encoding=UTF-8', Cookie => 'my_session_id'   },`

Comment: @user316389 Hmm, I think perhaps the `wrap` sub needs a `return $req` at the end. The documentation for HTTP::Request::Generator doesn't show it though.

Comment: if i do that i get new error `You need a request object, not a HASH object at E:\501dos.pl line 21.
`

Comment: @user316389 what's your entire `wrap` sub? Whatever it is, it's perhaps not generating an HTTP::Request object.

Comment: `          wrap => \&HTTP::Request::Generator::as_http_request,
` i was missing this line it was way at the end of `https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Generator` let me update original question.