# Run three shell script simultaneously

Tags: bash, shell

I have three shell script which I am running as below-

```
sh -x script1.sh

sh -x script2.sh

sh -x script3.sh
```

So each script is executed sequentially one at a time after previous one finished executing.

**Problem Statement:-**

Is there any way I can execute all the three above scripts at same time from a single window?
I just want to execute script1, script2, script3 at the same time. If you think of some CRON JOB scheduling `script1 at 3 AM, script2 at 3AM, script3 at 3AM` (all three scripts at the same time, simultaneously). That's what I need, I need to execute all the three scripts simultaneously.

Comment: Check out my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33106658/2032852 I shared a solution to that same problem with a script that allows you to run any number of programs, redirect their outputs to separated log files and wait for them to finish.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you want this?

```
$ sh -x script1.sh & sh -x script2.sh & sh -x script3.sh &
```

Update explanation :

- Run each script in background mode so that next command is run without waiting for current command to complete.
- `'&'` makes the scripts run in background so that prompt does not wait for it to complete
- `'&'` also can be used to chain commands on one line similar to running commands one by one on command line.

Comment: Can you explain what this will do? As I am not much familiar with unix stuff.

Comment: Rohan - you have a couple of errors there.  The error message will look like `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ;`.  You should remove both semicolons.  & is a valid command separator by itself.  Eg, try `echo a &; echo b &; echo c &` vs `echo a & echo b & echo c &`

Comment: Just for reference: `&` is a *control operator*, in this case used to create a *list* of *simple commands* that are executed in the *background*.

Comment: Thanks this is working. But suppose If I need to kill this process as it is running in background, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel sh -x ::: script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh
```

If the scripts are executable then you can even do:

```
parallel ::: script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

10 seconds installation:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

The `&` allows a process to run in the background.

```
sh -x script1.sh &
sh -x script2.sh &
sh -x script3.sh &
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. But suppose If I need to kill this task as it is running in background, how can I do that?

Comment: @user1419563 You can look up the `PID` (process ID).  Usually what I do is type `ps -ef | grep sh` to find all the shell scripts that are running. From there you can type `kill PID` which is not elegant but works.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you can create a script that calls these 3 or send them to background by adding a "&" at the end.

```
sh -x script1.sh &
sh -x script2.sh &
sh -x script3.sh &
```

Comment: And you can use `wait` to wait for all three of them to finish.

Comment: Thanks this is working. But suppose If I need to kill this task as it is running in background, how can I do that?

Comment: when you run it with the "&" it returns a process ID.
run
    kill <process id>