# ssh into multiple ec2 instances using bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, terminator

I want to open three ec2-instances simultaneously using bash script. I am using terminator for that. Following script opens three instances but only after one closed, other opens. Not simultaneously. That means, I have to close terminal with key1 instance then other terminal opens.

```
terminator -x ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x; 
terminator -x ssh -i key2 ec2-user@52.x.x.x; 
terminator -x ssh -i key3 ec2-user@52.x.x.x;
```

I want all of them to open in three sub windows in one terminal view. 
Also, while executing script, it gives me this message:

```
** (terminator:21982): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift><Control><Alt>a' failed!
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
<Window object at 0x7ff93c1776e0 (terminatorlib+window+Window at 0x2afa090)> is not in registered window list
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)

** (terminator:21995): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift><Control><Alt>a' failed!
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
```

I came with this code which works well. But this is for xterm. Can anyone help with same command for terminator?

```
(xterm -geometry 70x70-0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x;) & 
(xterm -geometry 70x70+485-200 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x;) &
(xterm -geometry 70x70+0-0 -e ssh -i key1 ec2-user@52.x.x.x;)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907721/run-three-shell-script-simultaneously

Comment: The error is coming from the fact that you are running terminator more than once presumably. Using `--new-tab` will probably help with that. And as the linked answer suggests running the commands in the background will prevent them from "blocking" the next command until after they finish.