# run two shell scripts on remote-machine

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I got a job to compile 32bit and 64bit version of the code,then get the package to the central server,to compile the code,I have to run a shell script and will call another script,due to the two scripts have nearly 1k lines,I don't want to meger to one script.

I have see the answer,and It just sovle parts of the problem
[run shell on remote-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine/2732991#2732991),Jason R. Coombs's anwser was great,when I run a shell scripts on local machine,In fact it runs in remote,what's most the output just shows in local machine,that's what's I want.for example when compile 32bit version failed ,I can see what's wrong on local machine and no need to ssh to the remote machine to compile again.
there two questions:

1.how to run two scripts in local machine I just dont't want to merge nearly 1k shell scripts together.

2.when I run the scripts,how to change the working dictory,example,I want the code run in /root/compile32 ,the shell scripts will git clone the code and compile && install using make and other actions.

Comment: You can run the scripts in a serial way by putting the run command of the second script in the last of the first script! Also, you can write a new script with no or minimal code: just two lines for executing both scripts
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907721/run-three-shell-script-simultaneously

Comment: a.sh will call b.sh, and b.sh is written in a bad way,if merge together there wull be lot of work to do.