# How to start inotifywait and another process from one shell script?

Tags: bash, inotify

I'm trying to start a server process (storescp, from dicom toolkit) and a file system watcher (via inotifywait) from a shell script.  Here's what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

INFOLDER=/home/dicom/storescp_in/
OUTFOLDER=/home/dicom/dicom_jpeg

#watch the input directory
inotifywait -m -e close_write "$INFOLDER" | while read dicomfile
do
mv "$INFOLDER""dicomfile"  "$OUTFOLDER""$dicomfile"

done    

# start the storescp server
storescp -v -od $INFOLDER 104
```

But inotifywait appears to be a blocking call (sorry, i'm coming at this from a javascript event driven kind of experience; I don't have much experience with Bash scripts).. is it possible to start my server and inotifywait in the same script?  how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the & operator, like in question
[How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-from-a-bash-script)

Seems to be just the thing!