# How to run tasks in parallel in bash without GNU parallel

Tags: bash

I would like to process 2000 files on a 64 core machine.  I have a python script `foo.py` which I run like this:

```
cat file0000.txt|./foo.py > out0000.txt
```

Ideally I would to split the 2000 files file0000.txt to file01999.txt into forty sets each of size 50 and run foo.py on each set in parallel.  For sets 1 to 4 out of 40 that would be the equivalent of the following:

```
cat file00[0-4][0-9] |./foo.py > outfile1.txt &
cat file00[5-9][0-9] |./foo.py > outfile2.txt &
cat file01[0-4][0-9] |./foo.py > outfile3.txt &
cat file01[5-9][0-9] |./foo.py > outfile4.txt &
```

Sadly the system I am running this on doesn't have `parallel` so I have to do  this without that very useful tool.

[Bash script processing commands in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543139/bash-script-processing-commands-in-parallel) looks similar but the most popular answer is not directly relevant and the second most popular answer uses `parallel` which I don't have access to.

Comment: What is the problem with `xargs` and `-P max-procs` option?

Comment: @Alper That could be the answer but  I have never used it. How would you use it for my problem?

Comment: Something like `ls -1 | xargs -I{} -P 5 sh -c "cat {} | ./foo.py > out{}.txt"`, Note: `ls -1` should be listing your input files and change `-P 5` as you like.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't install GNU Parallel? As per https://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Comment: @OleTange Sadly it's a centrally managed system and I am not allowed to.

Comment: @eleanora I apologise in advance, but I really do not understand how you can be allowed to run ./foo.py but not ./parallel. Can you explain the distinction why ./foo.py is allowed, but not ./parallel?

Comment: @OleTange It's the installing part I am not allowed to do.  I see from your very useful link that one option is to download it and run it as a normal user :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments: Do a personal installation of GNU Parallel which you are allowed to do if you are allowed to run your own scripts:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

And then:

```
ls | ~/bin/parallel 'cat {} | ./foo.py > {= s/file/out/ =}'
```