# How to run multiple commands at the same time in bash instead of running one after another?

Tags: bash, command

I need to run more than one command in bash without waiting to finishing first one and starting other command. The commands can be like this inside bash file.

```
#!/bin/bash
perl test.pl -i file1 -o out1
perl test.pl -i file2 -o out2
and so on
```

All should run at the same time in different cores instead of running one after another.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists and read for "background".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run multiple programs from a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 2):

Background them with `&`:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl test.pl -i file1 -o out1 &
perl test.pl -i file2 -o out2 &
```

Or better yet, use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). This will allow you to use multiple CPUs and lots more.