# Python - Import file from another directory, run script error

Tags: python, pandas, import

I have a pandas dataframe file in another directory shown below. I import that file, ES_15M_Trend_Identifier, as follows:

```
import sys 
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r"C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\ES")) 

import ES_15M_Trend_Identifier
ES_15M_Trend_Identifier.py
```

I'm folowing the directions given on SO:

[How to run multiple python file in a folder one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836557/how-to-run-multiple-python-file-in-a-folder-one-after-another)

but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'py'
```

I usually don't have problems importing other python files and don't think that's the issue. The error above is referring to the last line 'ES_15M_Trend_Identifier.py'

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by the line `ES_15M_Trend_Identifier.py`? (Hint: It is useless and causes the error.)

Comment: Haha I'm just trying to execute the entire file there. So I want to call the py file ES_15M_Trend_Identifier and then execute it.

Comment: The other file I'm importing creates a dataframe, then converts it to csv after modifying it.