# How to run multiple python files simultaneously?

Tags: python, terminal

I have python files (named in same way) in different folders. I want to run all python files at the same time with one script, any of the terminals (of the executed files) should not to be closed when the new terminal is opened. Which means, I want them to run simultaneously, each in a **new/different terminal**. What kind of script could do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run multiple python file in a folder one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836557/how-to-run-multiple-python-file-in-a-folder-one-after-another)

Comment: What operating system are you on? Your question can be answered with a batch file or shell script, depending on the platform you're on, unless you're looking for a pure Python solution for some reason?

Comment: I use windows. I prefer a python solution but I don't mind other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I just had to use:

> subprocess.Popen("python pathtoeachfile//file.py", creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

and loop over my files.