# How can I run multiple python instructions from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file example contents line by line:

```
python example.py (do some stuff 1)
python example.py (do some stuff 2)
python example.py (do some stuff 3)
python example.py (do some stuff nth)
```

Is there a simple script/way to run all those commands line by line from the text file in python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of "do some stuff"?  Are these args you're passing to the top-level script, or are you talking about calling functions that are defined in that module?

Comment: Running it a shell loop would be even easier. That'll depend on your shell.

Comment: can you use bash? `cat $file; while read line; do $line; done`

Comment: python seedrecover.py --wallet-type bip39 --addrs bc1qv87qf7prhjf2ld8vgm7l0mj59jggm6ae5jdkx2 --mnemonic "element entire sniff tired miracle solve shadow scatter hello never tank side sight isolate sister uniform advice pen praise soap lizard festival connect" --addr-limit 5

Comment: Perhaps this can help you with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836686/15794497

Comment: thank you so much for all feedback, let me study all examples provided regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.