# Best strategy to run multiple flyway migration in parallel

Tags: flyway

I want to upgrade multiple schemas on a legacy system running on a single mysql instance.

In development I have ~10 schemas, while in production I have ~100 schemas.

In development I was using a simple bash loop to start a `flyway migrate` for each schema:

```
schemas=$(echo "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=8192; select GROUP_CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME SEPARATOR ' ') from information_schema.SCHEMATA where SCHEMA_NAME like 'FOO_%'" | mysql -h$DB_URL -P$DB_PORT -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD -sN)
for schema in $schemas; do
    echo "Starting Migration for :  $schema"
    flyway -configFile=src/flyway.conf -user=$DB_USER -password=$DB_PASSWORD -url="jdbc:mysql://$DB_URL:$DB_PORT" -schemas=$schema -locations=filesystem:src/schema/ migrate 2>&1 | tee $schema.log &
done
```

This strategy was working fine in dev. In production I quickly max out the ram of the gitlab runner that runs the `flyway migrate`.

In your opinion what would be the best way to acheive the database migration as fast as possible without maxing out the ram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to limit the number of processes run in parallel. Currently you will run as many processes as schemas, in prod you have 100 so that uses up all the ram. There are many ways of achieving this including `pexec`, `parallel` and even `xargs`. I'll assume you have access to `xargs` the others need software to be installed.

[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) wrote a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44124618/5291110) with examples on how to use xargs with the -P option:

```
    -P, --max-procs=MAX-PROCS    Run up to max-procs processes at a time
```

EDIT: Updating with example after experimenting with -P.

This command demonstrates -P:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd\n" | xargs -i -P 2 sh -c 'touch {}.log; sleep 3;'
ls --full-time
```

Try this command with flyway:

```
$(echo "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=8192; select GROUP_CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME SEPARATOR ' ') from information_schema.SCHEMATA where SCHEMA_NAME like 'FOO_%'" | mysql -h$DB_URL -P$DB_PORT -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWORD -sN) | xargs -i -P 10 sh -c 'echo "Starting Migration for :  {}"; flyway -configFile=src/flyway.conf -user=$DB_USER -password=$DB_PASSWORD -url="jdbc:mysql://$DB_URL:$DB_PORT" -schemas={} -locations=filesystem:src/schema/ migrate 2>&1 | tee {}.log'
```