# running multiple commands in parallel in bash

Tags: bash, shell, wait

I want to run multiple scripts/commands in parallel in bash. 
Here is the bash script :

```
python test_script.py &
docker stop process &
docker stop process1 &
sleep(1)
wait

docker start process1 &
docker start process &
wait
```

Here, im running multiple dockers and want to start/stop docker when my script python test_script.py is running.

for ex: python script is running and on parallel i want to stop process & process1 docker. python script is still in-progress and then say wait or sleep for 1 min and start the process again.

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the following rules:

X; Y    Run X and then Y, regardless of success of X

X && Y  Run Y if X succeeded

X || Y  Run Y if X failed

X &     Run X in background.

Comment: Thanks Alex for answering. I'm looking to run these commands in parallel in script. In the mentioned bash script python test-script is running and then in parallel after some seconds i want to start/stop docker images.

Answer (score 1):

From your original description, it seems that we can organize the problem into two scripts

- A main python script `test_script.py`
- A docker restart script say `restart_docker.sh` which contains all the docker related commands that will be executed in sequence

  ```
  docker stop process
  sleep 1m
  docker start process
  ```

With `GNU parallel`, you can provide these two scripts as arguments to be executed in parallel

```
parallel ::: 'python test_script.py' 'bash restart_docker.sh'
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But the output of test_script.py is not getting listed in the console / CLI. Is there a way to display the script execution output with parallel command ?

Comment: What is the difference between executing the above shared command by you and parallel 'python test_script.py' ::: 'bash restart_docker.sh'

Comment: @Pooja Hmm that's odd, `parallel` should forward all the messages generated from each command to stdout, maybe you accidentally added a `&`?

Comment: @Pooja For the detail usage of the `parallel` syntax, you can always refer to its manual page. In short, by using `parallel ::: A B`, this means that A and B will run as separate commands while `parallel A ::: B` means that A is a command and B is an argument for A