# Mac OS X - running terminal commands async

Tags: macos

i would like to run two or more commands asynchronously.

How to achieve that? I need to run more cURL requests asynchronously.

Comment: Unless you have some other requirement, opening multiple shell windows is probably the simplest way...no need for fg/bg switching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `&` to send command to background.

```
$  pwd &
[1] 1720
/Users/gonczor
[1]+  Done                    pwd
```