# How to start multiple spring-boot applications using Maven, say Client on port 8081 and API on port 8080

Tags: maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a multi-module project developed using Spring Boot managed by Maven. There are two spring boot applications, say the API which runs on port 8081 and the thymeleaf client which runs on port 8080. I would want to bootrun both the applications in a single maven command from the root project. Currently, I am explicitly starting each of the application class. How do I achieve this using Maven.?

The project folder structure is as below.

```
1 RootProject - pom.xml
1.1--API(Spring Boot Project) with port 8080- pom.xml
1.2--Client(Spring Boot Project) with port 8081 - pom.xml
```

Thanks,
KR

Comment: Maven will only run the second module if the first one completes, but the Spring boot plugin won't complete unless the application is terminated. You can always define [a shell script that will run programs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script).