# How do I start react app with tailwind watch

Tags: tailwind-css, react-scripts

Here are my scrips in package.json. I created a project using create-react-app and want to introduce tailwind.

```
"build:css": "postcss src/theme/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles.css",
"watch:css": "postcss -w src/theme/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles.css",
"build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
"start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
```

when I run yarn start, the app is not started. Seems it stopped on watch. how can I have tailwind watch and start app?

Comment: can you include a codesandbox example - there's not enough information to give an answer

Answer (score 7):

So basically what's happening is that when you run two scripts it waits until the first will return something.
If you just start the development server before and then run `watch:css` it will work, because the development server will be started and then script that builds tailwind will be watching for changes.
If you arrange your scripts like this it should work:

`"build:css": "postcss src/theme/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles.css",
"watch:css": "postcss -w src/theme/tailwind.css -o src/assets/styles.css",
"build": "react-scripts build && npm run build:css",
"start": "react-scripts start && npm run watch:css",`

If this won't help you may use `concurrently` package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

or you could run them separately. `react-script start` in one console and `watch:css` in the second one, then the first will reload after any changes are made in `styles.css` and the second will rebuild `styles.css` when any change will be made in `tailwind.css`

Comment: concurrently helped me

Answer (score 4):

You can run commands concurrently with `&`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5553774/13214938 for more info.

```json
"start": "react-scripts start & npm run tailwind:watch && kill $!",
"tailwind:watch": "tailwindcss -i src/index.css -o src/build.css --watch"
```