# How to run function when NodeJS server starts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Hello I need to run a function on first start of the server, basically I want to put some constant data in the database. Yes, I could use just a in memory constant for this but I'd rather have it in my database because I am planning on using that data on some of my other servers in the future. The problem is, I am using NextJS and I want to host on the Vercel platform so I don't want to use a custom `server.js` file.

Is there any way to run a function only once when the server first starts in NextJS/NodeJS?

Comment: You can call that function into callback function of `server.listen()` or `app.listen()`

Comment: @DhavalDarji how do I do that without a custom server? Can you include a code sample please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Vercel platform is serverless: https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/introduction.

As it states in the documentation you can create a serverless function like so:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
}
```

If you wish to run a function after the build is done you can look at this answer:

[Next.js run function/script when starting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134289/next-js-run-function-script-when-starting-app)

You could also use `getServerSideProps` to run code before the page renders (on the server side) if that is what you mean with "app start".

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Comment: When using the solution from the linked question, the function runs twice every time a hot reload happens.. Although I'm guessing in production it should only run once ever(well, two times for some reason)?

Comment: @randomprogramming what do you mean with "app start"? The linked question runs after a build is done. If you wish to run some function on request you could do so in the getServerSideProps. I updated my answer.

Comment: I meant on app build, but I am wondering how will this solution work in production env? Since right now the function runs every time I open a new page.. Will the function in production trigger every time any new user opens the page?

Comment: No, the build is done once. You can see it in the Vercel log as well when the app is deploying on their platform. @randomprogramming

Comment: Okay that's what I was wondering, thanks!

Comment: No worries, happy coding :)