# Next.js execution of code before starting the application through, similar to APP_INITIALIZER from Angular

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can we execute code before starting our NextJS application logic? Specifically, I want to download data from the server before anything else happens, and write them to the repository.

That is, I need something analogous to [`APP_INITIALIZER` from Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER).

Comment: Similar to what's asked in this question: [Next.js run function/script when starting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134289/next-js-run-function-script-when-starting-app).