# How to call function when nextjs application start

Tags: next.js, backend

I am trying to add a guardian process for my NextJS application. it will start with the launch of my nextjs application, and then perform some jobs regularly(like backup data).

But I didn't find some "callback" or "eventListener" to let me call my startup function.

I tried to execute the startup function in `pages/_app.tsx`, but it was called every time when user accessed it, not only once when the nextjs application started.

The following is my expectation:

- Call only once when the entire nextjs application is started.
- No need to use a custom backend.(*There are already a lot of code accumulated on the default server of Next*)
- Can use the ability provided by Next, such as `TypeScript`, `Babel`, `export` / `import`, etc.
- The code in the nextjs application can directly Import related its function and use.

Can anyone provide some inspiration?

Comment: getStaticProps and getStaticPaths could be what you're looking for but it's hard to say without additional context.

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Next.js run function/script when starting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134289/next-js-run-function-script-when-starting-app)?

Comment: Thank you for your link @juliomalves, but I have seen this. the cost of switching to the custom server is too great, and using Webpack to call the startup function will cause other code cannot be directly `import` related methods

Comment: use the next/script `Script` component (call you data  in onLoad function). to run only single time,  use localStorage.