# Shell Script - Run shell commands in parallel in different bash sessions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a requirement to run database restore commands in parallel from shell scripts. Both the commands should run in different bash sessions in parallel.

The following are the commands I need to run.

```
sudo su - $user -c "db2 RESTORE DATABASE ${SDBP} FROM '/dbnfs/db2main/backups/${DB2DBP}' TAKEN AT $TIMESTAMPP ON '/data1/DB2/tablespaces/${DB2DBP}' , '/data2/DB2/tablespaces/${DB2DBP}'  DBPATH ON '/home/db2inst1' INTO ${DB2DBP} NEWLOGPATH '/data1/activelogs/${DB2DBP}' without rolling forward without prompting 2>&1"
sudo su - $user -c "db2 RESTORE DATABASE ${SDBS} FROM '/dbnfs/db2main/backups/${DB2DBS}' TAKEN AT $TIMESTAMPS ON '/data1/DB2/tablespaces/${DB2DBS}' , '/data2/DB2/tablespaces/${DB2DBS}'  DBPATH ON '/home/db2inst1' INTO ${DB2DBS} NEWLOGPATH '/data2/activelogs/${DB2DBS}' without rolling forward without prompting 2>&1"
```

Let me know how to achieve it.

Comment: Add `&` at end to run process in background

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want different bash sessions (perhaps due to long running commands), [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) command might be of interest to you.

You can create new named screens (sessions), let's call it `restore1` for the first command:

```
screen -S restore1
```

This will create a new screen. In this screen you can run your first command. Once command starts running, you can "detach" (`ctrl+a d`) from it.

Create another named `screen` called `restore2` for `SDBS`:

```
screen -S restore2
```

Run the second command here, then detach from it. You can check the screens (sessions) by:

```
screen -list
```

You can reattach to any of the screens with `screen -r <screen_name>`, to check on the status of that command. Example:

```
screen -r restore1
```