# Terminal script involving 2 terminals

Tags: bash, terminal, npm-scripts

Is it possible to make a command that does something, Opens another terminal and then does something there?
Im trying to combine the start up of a server and its api.

"god": "next dev && cd server && strapi develop"
I want the 'cd' part to start in a new terminal. Ive tried open -a terminal but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: So you just need to run those two commands in parallel?

Comment: Yeah exactly  that

Comment: "tried open -a terminal but it doesnt seem to work." what do you mean?

Comment: The command that others are saying opens another terminal

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `tmux` for that

```
tmux new-session \; \
  send-keys 'next dev' C-m \; \
  split-window -h -p 50 \; \
  send-keys 'cd server && strapi develop' C-m \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you simply need to run two commands in parallel. This can be achieved easily in bash:

```
command1 & command2  # will run command1, send it to background,
                     # and run command2 (which will be kept in foreground)
```

In your case:

```
next dev & cd server && strapi develop
```

You can read more about this here: [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: What did it do?

Comment: I followed what was said by you and what was on that page and it doesnt want to work on vs code,  It was a small time saver so its not a problem. Thanks anyway