# && in bash script using GNU "parallel"

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I would like to run my bash my_script.sh using GNU **parallel**:

```
parallel < my_script.sh
```

where my_script.sh is:

```
command1 && command2
command3 
command4
```

Will command1 and command2 run in parallel or sequentially.
In case I am not clear:
command1
command2
command3
command4

or

command1 -> command2
command3
command4

?

Thank you!

Comment: GNU `parallel` is a separate project, not part of bash, and it has its own tag.

Comment: @Charles Duffy. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script

Comment: @user123 Does & runs threads in time while parallel in differents cpus?

Comment: `&` runs **processes** in the background, not threads. You shouldn't really concern yourself with which CPU the OS uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` lets you do something based on whether the previous command completed successfully.

---

It will run like this:

```
command1 -> command2 (only if the exit status of "command1" is zero)
command3
command4
```

Comment: if I use semicolon instead of `&&`, will it run in parallel 1+2 - 3 - 4 ?

Comment: @aerijman Please read this article, especially section "Brute Force" should resolve your doubts (if you want to execute each command parallel).
[Get more done at the Linux command line with GNU Parallel](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/gnu-parallel). If you want to execute the command sequentially (line after line) use normal run: `./my_script.sh`