# how to run jar in parallel mode

Tags: java, multithreading

My External program from windows PC calls my jar thrice with different command line arguments like

```
java -jar xxx.jar  RT 1 runandroid ad.sh
java -jar xxx.jar RT 2 runlke adf.sh
java -jar xxx.jar RT 3 dfdf ssss.sh
```

my program is called but it runs in a sequential manner I want it to run in the parallel way how to achieve this.

I tried implementing the method with RT inside thread using runnable interface but still it works in sequential manner only

[image: code snippet]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and show the output from an example run.

Comment: No amount of multithreading is going to change the fact that the *calling shell* is waiting for the process to finish (short of doing insane shenanigans with daemon threads, which you *should not* do). You need to change how you invoke the program to make that happen.

Comment: are u asking about starting shell parallel jobs ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script

Comment: no i want to maintain separate thread for each individual command from remote setup