# How do i get parallel jobs working on failure

Tags: scheduling, restart, rundeck, resume

If I have a set of parallel jobs and 1 fails and the other succeeds.
I try the resume execution/retry failed nodes, it triggers both the jobs again.
Is there any setting in rundeck which can trigger only the failed job and not rerun the entire group again ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: when you mean "If I have a set of parallel jobs" it's about jobs launched from a parent job via job reference step? (parallelly)

Comment: Just 2 jobs in the entire group, each via job reference. they are set to trigger in parallel. ! fails and 1 succeeds, using the resume should trigger only the failed job but both the jobs get triggerred. any reason why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that job reference steps is running on a single job, by design, rundeck consider that as a parent job exection and not individual executions (child jobs, the parallel jobs). If you want to avoid this, you will run these jobs individually (in a job [calling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004814/10426011) each job using [rd cli](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) or Rundeck [api](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#api-version-number)) in a inline-script step.

In that way you can retry only the failed execution.

Now, to resume since a failed step, you can use the [Job Resume Plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/execution-lifecycle/job-resume.html#job-resume-plugin-enterprise) (only for Rundeck Enterprise). The plugin allows to resume in the job failed step.