# Run Python script multiple times at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, multithreading

Hey I have the following "problem". I am currently writing a python script that checks certificates for CRL. You give this script the certificate in the command line and it checks it. This script should now be started several times in the Linux terminal at the same time. Does this work with a normal script without multithreading or _threads or do I need something like this? If yes, which library do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run multiple shell commands by using & between commands to run them in parallel:

```bash
cmd arg1 & cmd arg2 & cmd arg3
```

for example

Comment: Okay how would you do it if you both 2x start the same script with it and both need to access a file (write and read) because global block variables can not be set then?!

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to do this.

Using only bash, See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3004814/9465840)

Using Parallel package, See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018124/9465840)

Install parallel before using it with `sudo apt install parallel -y`.