# Running shell scripts in parallel from a list of files

Tags: bash, loops, shell, parallel-processing

I have a list of scripts doing their own thing (they are actually Rscripts reading modifying and writing files) like this:

```
## Script 1
echo "1" > file1.out
## Script 2
echo "2" > file2.out
## Script 3
echo "3" > file3.out
```

These are saved in different scripts as follow:

```
## Writing script 1
echo "echo \"1\" > file1.out" > script1.task
## Writing script 2
echo "echo \"2\" > file2.out" > script2.task
## Writing script 3
echo "echo \"3\" > file3.out" > script3.task
```

**Is there a way to run all these scripts in parallel using the file names?**
In a loop it'd look like this:

```
for task_file in *.task
do
  sh ${task_file}
done
```

Comment: Ampersand is your friend. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script?rq=1

Comment: You can run the scripts in the background, and after the loop use `wait` to wait until all are finished. However, how many processes are you planning to run in parallel? Are you sure that your machine can handle them?

Comment: Thanks both, I will use the `&` and `wait` design. The number of tasks generated is function of the number of cores available so the pipeline is designed to be portable on any machine (a one core one will just end up being a regular for loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following advice from [Andre Wildberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9462095/andre-wildberg) and [user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428) here's a solution using `&` just for the record:

```
for task_file in *.task
do
  sh ${task_file} &
done
wait
```

Comment: Put the `wait` outside the loop, otherwise it just does the same as without the `&`. E.g. `for i in {1..5};do sleep 2 & echo "OK"; wait; done` vs `for i in {1..5};do sleep 2 & echo "OK"; done; wait`

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 3 the answer is to use &.

But if you have 1000s:

```
seq 10000 | parallel 'echo {} > file{}.out'
```