# How to do multiple commands in bash at the sametime via a for loop?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I'm trying to optimize a compression service (my own) on a 104 CPU machine.

In order to do this I'm splitting up video files doing the following

```
ffmpeg -i test.MOV -threads 3 \
       -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 00:05 \
       -reset_timestamps 1 \
       out%02d.MOV
```

Then I'm compressing each one

```
for f in ./*MOV; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "./compressed/${f##*/}"; done
```

But in order for this to be optimized I need to go over the files at the same time as it seems FFMPEG caps out at 2-3 threads.

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
for f in ./*MOV; do (trap 'kill 0' SIGINT; ffmpeg -i "$f" "./compressed/${f##*/}"); done
```

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: You can do it with xargs or GNU parallel, see this answer (and the one before it)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44124618/3833426

Comment: @John thanks for the pointer, can't seem to get this to work inside this loop though

Comment: @OliverDixon - how many files you need to process - will the 104 cores will always be enough for all files in parallel, or do you need to phase the execution at a fix number of concurrent threads, etc ? chatpgt solution works, but you can probably get more mileage using xargs.

Answer (score 3):

Using xargs parallel execution, possible to achieve the above without having to build job control (e.g. `[[ $(jobs -p | wc -l) -ge $parallel_processes ]]` in above script) in bash.

```
ls ./*MOV | xargs -P4 -L1 sh -c 'ffmpeg -i $0 ./compressed/${0##/}'
```

Also, xargs will take care of properly cancelling outstanding jobs (e.g., ctrl/c, or similar).

You can get more fancy things done with 'parallel' - limiting concurrency based on actual load, etc.

Comment: It exits too early for the next task. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @OliverDixon  Can you share your script/error ? I updated the posting - it was only printing the command, without execution. I removed the "echo".

Comment: Well it doesn't wait for the next command @-dash-o

Comment: Are you putting it into the background with "&"

Comment: @OliverDixon - does the modified command (without the echo) work ? Consider adding "-t" after `xargs` before '-P4'  to produce verbose output.