# Building python backend sever and js frontend

Tags: python, node.js, package.json

I use a web application that runs Python fast API in the backend and electron+vite+vue in the frontend.
How can we build and run both the front end and the backend in the same shell?
I found one way to run a script to build a Python backend in package.json. Is this good practice? If not what are the alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run multiple programs in parallel from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004811/how-do-you-run-multiple-programs-in-parallel-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

To build and run both the frontend and backend in the same shell, you can use a tool like concurrently or npm-run-all. These tools allow you to run multiple commands simultaneously in the same terminal window.

Install concurrently:

```
npm install concurrently --save-dev
```

Modify the "scripts" section of your package.json to include a new "dev" script that runs both the backend and frontend:

`"scripts": { "dev": "concurrently \"cd backend && uvicorn main:app --reload\" \"cd frontend && npm run dev\"" }`

Run the "dev" script:

```
npm run dev
```