# Running multiple executable parallel with limitation to 5

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am running some larger amount (100) of calculations. Each calculation needs 5 hours to finish and can run only on one core. So in order to make whole process more efficient i need to run 5 (or more, depends on number of cpus) of them at same time.
I have 100 folders and in each is one executable. How can I run all 100 executable in the way that only 5 are running at the same time?

I have tried xargs as seen: [Parallelize Bash script with maximum number of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160/parallelize-bash-script-with-maximum-number-of-processes)

`cpus=5
find . -name ./*/*.exe | xargs --max-args=1 --max-procs=$cpus  echo`

I can't find the way to run them. Echo only prints paths on screen.

Comment: Do your `.exe` files have exec permissions? How do you normally call them?

Comment: @vintnes I call them liki this: ./name.exe

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the input as the command by specifying a substitution pattern and using that as the command:

```
$ printf '%s\n' uname pwd | xargs -n 1 -I{} {}
Linux
/data/data/com.termux/files/home
```

or more easily but less directly by using `env` as the command, since that will execute its first argument:

```
printf '%s\n' uname pwd | xargs -n 1 env
```

In your case, your full command might be:

```
find . -name '*.exe' | xargs -n 1 -P 5 env
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What kind of output do you get?